# Command to watch and bundle using brfs without watchify

Tags: javascript, watchify, brfs

I'm trying to replicate the behavior of `watchify` with the `brfs` transform, but I need to use `brfs` directly because I want to avoid the additional code added to the script when using `require` with browserify/watchify. Using `brfs` directly simply replaces `require(theFile)` with its contents and nothing else.

Using this command to bundle the following code produces my intended result:

```
brfs main.js > bundle.js
```

```
// main.js
var fs = require('fs');
var templates = {
    'header': fs.readFileSync('app/templates/header.html', 'utf8'),
    'nav-menu': fs.readFileSync('app/templates/nav-menu.html', 'utf8')
};
```

How do I set something up to watch for changes and have `brfs` bundle the script again when something changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consider this approach using the `brfs` programmatic api to be most proper. The only difference from the example we discussed in the js chat is that you need to use `fs.createReadStream` to pipe the file into `brfs`, rather than passing the filename directly to `brfs` as we were doing.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var brfs = require('brfs');
var fs   = require('fs');

// task without watch
gulp.task('bundle-templates', function() {
  fs.createReadStream('main.js')
    .pipe(brfs())
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('bundle.js'))
  ;
});

// this runs the `bundle-templates` task before starting the watch (initial bundle)
gulp.task('watch-templates', ['bundle-templates'], function() {
  // now watch the templates and the js file and rebundle on change
  gulp.watch([
    'templates/*.html',
    'main.js'
  ], ['bundle-templates']);
});
```

Now run this command and you're all set:

```
gulp watch-templates
```

`gulp` is not necessary here. You can recreate this using any task runner or by executing a node script directly. You can use [**gaze**](https://github.com/shama/gaze) directly to watch the files, which is the same watcher that gulp is using for `gulp.watch`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [gulp-shell](http://npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell),

then the gulp task would be

```
gulp.task('default', shell.task(['brfs main.js > bundle.js']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would fit your situation somehow... but you can also use this plugin that will detect new files and pipe them out:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newy/

example with using many less files and compare against one concatenated css file:

```
function lessVersusOneFile(projectDir, srcFile, absSrcFile) {
    //newy gives projectDir arg wich is '/home/one/github/foo/` 
    var compareFileAgainst = "compiled/css/application.css";

    var destination = path.join(projectDir, compareFileAgainst);
    // distination returned will be /home/one/github/foo/compiled/css/application.css 
    return destination;
}
// all *.less files will be compared against 
// /home/one/github/foo/compiled/css/application.css 

gulp.task('compileLessToCss', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/css/**/*.less')
        .pipe(newy(lessVersusOneFile))
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('compiled/css'));
});
```